# Estou fazendo um jogo, e na linha 36 deu esse erro Uncaught ReferenceError: resetInterval is not defined. Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>My game</title>
    <script src ="Sprite.js"></script>
    <Style>
            canvas {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;   
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                margin: auto;
            }
        </Style>
    </head>
    <body onload="main()">
        <script>
        //games variable >variáveis do jogo
            var canvas, ctx, Altura, Largura, maxJumps = 4, speed = 6, actualState, record, img,

        pointsForNewPhase = [5, 15, 21, 29, 38],    
        actualPhase = 0,    

            labelNewPhase = {
        texto: "",
        opacidade: 0.0,

        fadeIn: function(dt){
           var fadeInId = setInterval(function() {
             if(labelNewPhase.opacidade < 1.0)
            labelNewPhase.opacidade += 0.01;

             else{
                resetInterval(fadeInId); // Erro acontece nessa linha
             } 

            }, 10 * dt);
            },

        fadeOut: function(dt){
            var fadeOutId = setInterval(function() {
             if(labelNewphase.opacidade > 1.0)
            labelNewPhase.opacidade -= 0.01;

             else{
            resetInterval(fadeOutId); 
             }   

             }, 10 * dt);   
        }
        },

        states = {
                play: 0,
                playing: 1,
                youLose: 2
            },
            floor = {
                y: 550,
                x: 0,
        altura: 50,
                //color: "#ffdf70", // cor do chão em amarelo queimado


        update: function() {
            this.x -= speed;

            if (this.x <= -30){
                    this.x += 30;
            }
        },

        design: function () {
                    spriteFloor.design(this.x, this.y);
            spriteFloor.design(this.x + spriteFloor.largura, this.y);
                }
            },

        block = {
                x: 50,
                y: 0,
                altura: spriteBoneco.altura,
                largura: spriteBoneco.largura,
                //color: "#ff4e4e", // cor do bloquinho em vermelho
                gravity: 1.6,
                speed: 0,
                jumpForce: 26.6,
                hmanyJumps: 0, // How many Jumps = Quantos pulos
        score: 0,
        rotation : 0,

        lifes: 3,
        colliding: false,

        update: function () {
                    this.speed += this.gravity;
                    this.y += this.speed;
            this.rotation += Math.PI / 180 * speed;                    

            if (this.y > floor.y - this.altura && actualState != states.youLose) {
                        this.y = floor.y - this.altura;
                        this.hmanyJumps = 0;
            this.speed = 0;
                    }

                },

        jump: function () {
                    if (this.hmanyJumps < maxJumps) {
                        this.speed = -this.jumpForce;
                        this.hmanyJumps++;
                    }
                },

        reset: function () {
            this.speed = 0;
            this.y = 0;

            if (this.score > record) {
                localStorage.setItem("record", this.score);
                record = this.score;
            }

            this.lifes = 3;
            this.score = 0;

            speed = 6;
            actualPhase = 0;
        },

        design: function () {
             // operaçoes para rotacionar
             ctx.save();
             ctx.translate(this.x + this.largura / 2, this.y + this.altura / 2);
             ctx.rotate(this.rotation);          
             spriteBoneco.design(-this.largura / 2, -this.altura / 2);            
             ctx.restore();
                }
            };
            obstacles = {
                _obs: [],
        _scored: false,
                colors: ["#ffbc1c", "#ff1c1c", "#ff85e1", "#52a7ff", "#78ff5d"], // cor dos 

obstaculos
                timeInsert: 0,

        insert: function () {
                    this._obs.push({
                        x: Largura,
                        // largura: 30 + Math.floor(21 * Math.random()),
                        largura: 50,
            altura: 30 + Math.floor(120 * Math.random()),
                        color: this.colors[Math.floor(5 * Math.random())]
                    });

                    this.timeInsert = 30 + Math.floor(21 * Math.random());
                },

        update: function () {
                    if (this.timeInsert == 0)
                        this.insert();
                    else
                        this.timeInsert--;

            for (var i = 0, size = this._obs.length; i < size; i++) {
                        var obs = this._obs[i];

                        obs.x -= speed;

            if (!block.colliding && obs.x <= block.x + block.largura && block.x <= 

obs.x + obs.largura && floor.y - obs.altura <= block.y + block.altura) {
                block.colliding = true;         

            setTimeout(function() { 
                block.colliding = false;    
            }, 500);


            if(block.lifes >= 1)
               block.lifes--;

                else
                   actualState = states.youLose;
            }

            else if(obs.x <= 0 && !obs._scored){
                block.score++;
                obs._scored = true; 

            if(actualPhase < pointsForNewPhase.length && block.score == 

pointsForNewPhase[actualPhase])
                hasPassedPhase(); 
            }
                        else if (obs.x <= -obs.largura) {
                            this._obs.splice(i, 1);
                            size--;
                            i--;
                        }
                    }
                },

        clean: function (){
            this._obs = [];

        },

        design: function () {
                    for (var i = 0, size = this._obs.length; i < size; i++) {
                        var obs = this._obs[i];
                        ctx.fillStyle = obs.color;
                        ctx.fillRect(obs.x, floor.y - obs.altura, obs.largura, obs.altura);
                    }                       
                }
            };
        function click(event) {                
            if (actualState == states.playing)
                     block.jump();

            else if (actualState == states.play){
                 actualState = states.playing;

            } 
            else if (actualState == states.youLose && block.y >= 2 * Altura) {
                 actualState = states.play;
                 obstacles.clean();
                 block.reset();         
            }
               }

           function hasPassedPhase() {
           speed++;
           actualPhase++;
           block.lifes++;

           labelNewPhase.texto = "Level" + actualPhase;
           labelNewPhase.fadeIn(0.4);

        setTimeOut(function () {
           labelNewPhase.fadeOut(0.4);  
            }, 800);
               }    

            function main() {
        Altura = window.innerHeight;
                Largura = window.innerWidth;
                if (Largura >= 500) {
                    Largura = 600;
                    Altura = 600;
                }

                canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = Largura;
                canvas.height = Altura;
                canvas.style.border = "1px solid #000"; // borda preta para a canvas
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                document.addEventListener("mousedown", click);

                actualState = states.play;
                record = localStorage.getItem("record");

        if (record == null)
            record = 0;

        var image = "image";
        img = new Image();
        img.src = "imagens/sheet.png";


        roda();
            }

            function roda() {
                update();
                design();
                window.requestAnimationFrame(roda);
            }

            function update() {
                if(actualState == states.playing)
                    obstacles.update();

        floor.update();
        block.update();     
            }

            function design() {
                //ctx.fillStyle = "#50beff"; // cor da tela em azul
                //ctx.fillRect(0, 0, Largura, Altura);

        bg.design(0, 0);


        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff"; // cor da pontuação durante o jogo
        ctx.font = "50px Arial";
        ctx.fillText(block.score, 30, 60);
        ctx.fillText(block.lifes, 540, 60);

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, " + labelNewPhase.opacidade + ")";   
        ctx.fillText(labelNewPhase.texto, canvas.width / 2 - ctx.measureText

(labelNewPhase.texto).width / 2, canvas.height / 3);

        if (actualState == states.playing)
                    obstacles.design();        

        floor.design();
                block.design();

        if (actualState == states.play)
            play.design(Largura / 2 - play.largura / 2, Altura / 2 - play.altura / 2);

                if (actualState == states.youLose) {
            youLose.design(Largura / 2 - youLose.largura / 2, Altura / 2 - 

youLose.altura / 2 - spriteRecord.altura / 2);

            spriteRecord.design(Largura / 2 - spriteRecord.largura / 2, Altura / 2 + 

youLose.altura / 2 - spriteRecord.altura / 2 - 25);

        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        ctx.fillText(block.score, 375, 390);

        if (block.score > record) {                   
            novel.design(Largura / 2 - 170, Altura / 2 + 30);
            ctx.fillText(record, 420, 470);
        }

        else
            ctx.fillText(record, 420, 470);
        }                
            }
            //intialize the game > inicializa o jogo
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Onde estás a definir essa função?

Comment: pois então, eu ja tentei definir, e dai da outro erro dizendo que resetInterval não é o construtor ou não é uma função.

Comment: Tentei emular o código que passou, obtive o erro: `ReferenceError: spriteBoneco is not defined`

Comment: isso ocorreu por tu não ter as imagens, e nem o arquivo sprite, não tem nenhuma ideia do que eu poderia fazer?

Comment: Seria esse o repositório do jogo no git? https://github.com/alvesfilipe/Jump-js

Comment: era isso mesmo, estava seguindo o tutorial dele, no tutorial ele colocou desse jeito que falei, mas nesse outro, ele colocou clear e resolveu o problema, muito obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que o erro é de sintaxe, troque `resetInterval` por `clearInterval`

```
var fadeInId = setInterval(function() {
    if(labelNewPhase.opacidade < 1.0)
        labelNewPhase.opacidade += 0.01;

    else{
        clearInterval(fadeInId);
    } 

}, 10 * dt);
```

Comment: vlw denis deu certinho muito obrigado

Comment: De nada, você pode [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/), assim outras pessoas saberão que deu certo

Comment: e como eu faço isso? sou novo aqui